# bigrquery: Create a BigQuery table with geoJSON files doesn't work

Tags: r, google-bigquery, bigrquery

I'd like to create a BigQuery table with `geoJSON files`, despite the `geoJSON`is an accepted format in BQ (`NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON`) and `bq_fields specification, or something coercible to it (like a data frame)` the function `bq_table_create()` of the `bigrquery` package doesn't work. In my example below the output error is `Erro: Unsupported type: list`:

```
library(sf)
library(bigrquery)
library(DBI)
library(googleAuthR)
library(geojsonsf)
library(geojsonR)


# Convert shapefile to geoJSON 
stands_sel <- st_read(
  "D:/Dropbox/Stinkbug_Ml_detection_CMPC/dashboard/v_08_CMPC/sel_stands_CMPC.shp")

# Open as geoJSON
geo <- sf_geojson(stands_sel)

# Convert geoJSON to data frame 
geo_js_df <- as.data.frame(geojson_wkt(geo))
str(geo_js_df)
# 'data.frame': 2 obs. of  17 variables:
#  $ SISTEMA_PR: chr  "MACRO ESTACA - EUCALIPTO" "SEMENTE - EUCALIPTO"
#  $ ESPECIE   : chr  "SALIGNA" "DUNNI"
#  $ ID_UNIQUE : chr  "BARBANEGRA159A" "CAMPOSECO016A"
#  $ CICLO     : num  2 1
#  $ LOCALIDADE: chr  "BARRA DO RIBEIRO" "DOM FELICIANO"
#  $ ROTACAO   : num  1 1
#  $ CARACTER_1: chr  "Produtivo" "Produtivo"
#  $ VLR_AREA  : num  8.53 28.07
#  $ ID_REGIAO : num  11 11
#  $ CD_USO_SOL: num  2433 9053
#  $ DATA_PLANT: chr  "2008/04/15" "2010/04/15"
#  $ ID_PROJETO: chr  "002" "344"
#  $ CARACTERIS: chr  "Plantio Comercial" "Plantio Comercial"
#  $ PROJETO   : chr  "BARBA NEGRA" "CAMPO SECO"
#  $ ESPACAMENT: chr  "3.00 x 2.50" "3.5 x 2.14"
#  $ CD_TALHAO : chr  "159A" "016A"
#  $ geometry  :List of 2
#   ..$ : 'wkt' chr "MULTIPOLYGON (((-51.2142 -30.3517,-51.2143 -30.3518,-51.2143 -30.3518,-51.2143 -30.3519,-51.2143 -30.3519,-51.2"| __truncated__
#   ..$ : 'wkt' chr "MULTIPOLYGON (((-52.3214 -30.4271,-52.3214 -30.4272,-52.3214 -30.4272,-52.3215 -30.4272,-52.3215 -30.4272,-52.3"| __truncated__
#  - attr(*, "wkt_column")= chr "geometry"

# Insert information inside BQ
bq_conn <-  dbConnect(bigquery(),
                       project = "my-project",
                       use_legacy_sql = FALSE
)

# First create the table
players_table = bq_table(project = "my-project", dataset = "stands_ROI_2021", table = "CF_2021")
bq_table_create(x = players_table, fields = as_bq_fields(geo_js_df))
Erro: Unsupported type: list
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can upload data frame with a list-type column on BigQuery by using `bq_table_upload()` syntax. Try this on your script instead of `bq_table_create()`,

```
bq_table_upload(players_table, geo_js_df)
```

For your reference, I tried this on my end using this sample data with a list-type column:

```
d <- data.frame(id = 1:2,
                   name = c("Jon", "Mark"),
                   children = I(list(c("Mary", "James"),
                                     c("Greta", "Sally")))
                )
```

R console:

[image]

Created BQ table:

[image]

[image]

**EDIT:**

As per this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/geospatial-data#loading_geojson_data), `FeatureCollection` is not yet supported in BigQuery, however there is an ongoing feature request you can find [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/130756766). Workaround is to convert the GeoJson file to BigQuery new-line-delimited JSON before converting it to dataframe.

To convert GeoJson file to BigQuery new-line-delimited JSON, follow these [steps](https://github.com/mentin/geoscripts/tree/master/geojson2bq):

1. Install node.js.
2. Add packages:

```
npm install fs JSONStream line-input-stream yargs
```

3. Clone the github repository:

```
git clone https://github.com/mentin/geoscripts.git
```

4. Change directory:

```
cd geoscripts/geojson2bq/
```

4. Convert GeoJson file to BigQuery new-line-delimited JSON:

```
node geojson2bqjson.js sel_stands.geojson > out.json
```

Using the new-line-delimited JSON file, convert this to dataframe in the R console, then use bq_table_upload() to upload the data to BigQuery.

```
library(bigrquery)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyverse)
library(jsonlite)

out <- stream_in(file('out.json'))

projectid<-"my-project"
datasetid<-"my-dataset"

bq_conn <-  dbConnect(bigquery(), 
                      project = projectid,
                      dataset = datasetid, 
                      use_legacy_sql = FALSE)

players_table = bq_table(project = "my-project", dataset = "my-dataset", table = "CF_2021_test5")

bq_table_upload(players_table, out)

bq_table_download(players_table)
```

R console:
[image]

BigQuery table:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi @Mabel A. thank you very much, not yet because if I try:

`bq_table_upload(players_table, geo_js_df)`
`Erro: No method asJSON S3 class: MULTIPOLYGON`

The ideia is saved as a JSON/geoJSON file and if I convert to table I don't have spatial geometries format.

Comment: @Leprechault can you provide a sample geoJSON file?

Comment: thanks, the same file in geoJSON format: [https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Leprechault/trash/main/sel_stands.geojson]

Comment: Hi @Leprechault please check my answer, I updated it with additional information.

Comment: you can use `geojsonsf::sf_geojson(stands_sel, atomise = TRUE)` to give you line-delimited geojson